# What can be done to make c++ compiler accept 2_147_483.78 as a valid floating point number

Tags: c++

I have a c++ auto generated code from client's input file . Somehow the clients prefer to write floating point numbers as 2_147_483.78 where as per them _ represent nothing and should be ideally replaced with emptiness but they have kept that for readability purposes & wont remove those . What can be done in a minimal manner for the auto-generated code to work

Comment: You could probably process the source code with a regex replacement to remove those. Can you give us an example of this code?

Comment: Aye, just apply your favorite string techniques, be it regex or a simple iteration and delete.

Comment: What generates the c++ file ? May be some script/application ?  I'd suggest modifying the script/application else write a new script script to post process those files. You can't ask compiler to do this. You'll have to modify the c++ source somehow

Answer (score 3):

When the C++ standards committee decided (on formulating the C++14 standard) upon the tick ' for a decimal separator as opposed to a different character (e.g. the underscore) they did it for good reason: the grammar would break horribly otherwise.

I don't think it's possible to solve your problem in full generality especially if your client uses a leading underscore on such a number since then it would be interpreted as a variable name which *could* change the program behaviour.

So if you were to embark on some kind of preprocessor you'd always be up against edge cases, some of which could be pernicious and go unnoticed.

Your best bet I think is to convince your client to refrain from doing this, or advise them to use the tick ' rather than the underscore, and migrate your toolchain to C++14. Your client would write

`2'147'483.78`

rather than

`2_147_483.78`

Comment: Huh, I had no idea you could put those in literals.

Comment: You can from C++14 onwards.

Comment: That would explain why I hadn't heard of it